If polynomial is irreducible over finite field $\mathbb F_p$ then it is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$.
According to link, It is easy to show its contrapositive which is If the polynomial is reducible over $\mathbb Z$ then it is reducible over finite field $\mathbb F_p$ of order $p$.
Let $f(x)=g(x)h(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$ is reducible such that $g,h$ are non-unit. Then taking modulo prime $p$ shows that $$\overline{f(x)}=\overline{g(x)}\hspace{0.2cm}\overline{h(x)} \mod p.$$
How can I conclude that $\overline{g(x)}$ or $\overline{h(x)}$ is not unit in $\mathbb F_p$? If I say so then $\overline{f(x)}$ is reducible over $\mathbb F_p$?.

The assumption that the leading coefficients is not a multiple of $p$ is part of the statements.
